# SQL Join gives wrong results (creates duplicates)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my SQL join query. I have looked up other suggested answers and tried to apply it to my query, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(p.quantity)
FROM stocktake_scans p

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT stocktake_area_id
FROM stocktake_areas
WHERE stocktake_id =8592 AND area_checked = 1
)d ON d.stocktake_area_id = p.stocktake_area_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM stocktake_scan_edit
    WHERE user_id =46521
    )e ON e.user_id = p.stocktake_staff_id
WHERE p.stocktake_staff_id = 46521
```

And it gives me a result of 42, while I should get only 6. What is missing from the query?

Comment: Post sample data and desired output

Comment: can you advise what result you are getting from the simplified query below:  SELECT SUM(p.quantity)
FROM stocktake_scans p WHERE p.stocktake_staff_id = 46521

Comment: I get a result of 6 when I use the simplified query

Comment: ok so there are extra rows being returned in your joins

Comment: Yes, when I remove the SUM() to see exactly what is being returned, I get a list of 1,3,2 multiple times, so there is something incorrect with the joins but I can't figure out what and where

Comment: ok here will be the issue, please count how many records could be inflating your row count form the below:  SELECT count(user_id) as count, user_id
    FROM stocktake_scan_edit
    WHERE user_id =46521 group by user_id having count(user_id)>1

Comment: and the same for your other joined query please?

Comment: SELECT SUM(p.quantity)
FROM stocktake_scans p

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT distinct  stocktake_area_id
FROM stocktake_areas
WHERE stocktake_id =8592 AND area_checked = 1
)d ON d.stocktake_area_id = p.stocktake_area_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT distinct  user_id
    FROM stocktake_scan_edit
    WHERE user_id =46521
    )e ON e.user_id = p.stocktake_staff_id
WHERE p.stocktake_staff_id = 46521 try adding distinct of you are getting dupes, although really you could do with understanding what is causing dupe rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have extra records with the same ID in your joined table that is where you are getting multiple rows returned from which is then calculating wrong in your sum, please try the below.

```
 SELECT SUM(p.quantity) FROM stocktake_scans p LEFT JOIN ( SELECT distinct stocktake_area_id FROM stocktake_areas WHERE stocktake_id =8592 AND area_checked = 1 )d ON d.stocktake_area_id = p.stocktake_area_id LEFT JOIN ( SELECT distinct user_id FROM stocktake_scan_edit WHERE user_id =46521 )e ON e.user_id = p.stocktake_staff_id WHERE p.stocktake_staff_id = 46521
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, that was it! I did have multiple user_id in stocktake_scan_edit as it is not primary key (can't be). This seems to have solved the problem!